# I need help switching between forms after a certain amount of time goes by

Tags: vb.net, timer

I am creating a game and I want the player to only be allowed on one form for approx. 15 seconds or depending on the question on the form, it may be a sooner time such as 7 seconds but for the timer it is only in milliseconds, will i have to make it 7000 for the interval or if there is a more simple way could someone lead me onto the correct path? im not asking for code just for a direction to go with this, thanks :) if you need more information because i did not explain it very well just ask and ill do my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly as you say.  If you want to do something after 7 seconds then you set the `Interval` of a `Timer` to 7000.  `Interval` is an `Integer` so it can support values over 24 days.

Actually, another option for one-off actions nowadays is the `Task.Delay` method.  I'd go with the `Timer` though, because you will need to act on the UI thread and the `Task` will act on a secondary thread.

Comment: Thank you for the help, ive made the program using the timer and it works really well and ill look into the Task.Delay method.